# How to set bar width in bargraph using AchartEngine in android

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to set bar width in bargraph so that every bar graph shown is of given size. I have  generated bar graph using achart engine  so please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

If your series contain more than one element per series then I suggest you use `renderer.setBarSpacing()`. Tweak the parameter until you get the desired look.

If there is only one element in your series then you can use `renderer.setBarWidth()`.